# Why i am unable to have a rich text editor inside our document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rich-text

I have created a document library inside our online communication site collection, and inside it i added a new site column of Multiple line of text +Rich text capabilities as follow:-

[image]

but when i upload a document and try to edit the above column, i will not have the ability to add any rich text to the fields + i can only add 255 characters as follow:-

[image]

any idea why i can not have a rich text editor field inside our document library?

Answer (score 1):

Open the site in SharePoint designer->Click on your library->Click on Edit columns under Customization->Double click on the column which you want enable Rich Text functionality-> select the checkbox which says Rich Text and hit OK and then Save.

[image]

Reference:

https://www.sharepointeurope.com/rich-text-column-sharepoint-document-library/

Comment: thanks for the valuable reply,, but do you know why this is not set by default ?